# How is it possible to come back to the same page?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I am new at Objective C. I am just trying to build an iphone app. I have created some NIB file, and i have gone to other NIB file by creating an object and using this code:

```
scoreViewController *sviewController = [[scoreViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"scoreViewController" bundle:nil];
self.scoreView = sviewController;
[sviewController release];
// Setup the animation
[self.navigationController pushViewController:self.scoreView animated:YES];
```

Now I want to come back to the same page. For this case I have done the same work, but it does not work when I add the previous page header file name.

```
mainViewController *mainviewController = [[mainViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"mainViewController" bundle:nil];
self.mcoreView = mainviewController;
[mainviewController release];
// Setup the animation
[self.navigationController pushViewController:self.mcoreView animated:YES];
```

So, I will be most grateful if you were so nice to post your comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not 100% sure what you are asking, but I think you want to go back from the the second controller to the first. What you are doing here is instantiating a second instance of the first controller (so you now have 3 controllers), and pushing it onto the stack. Assuming I have this correct, then if you want to move back to the first controller you should be popping the second controller off the stack, not adding a 3rd:

```
//mainViewController *mainviewController = [[mainViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"mainViewController" bundle:nil];
//self.mcoreView = mainviewController;
//[mainviewController release];

// Setup the animation
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```